# Why Supplier instead of Producer?

Tags: java, java-8

This is a really simple question, but someone here must know, so here's an easy way for them to get some points.

In Java 8, there are four categories of functional interfaces in the `java.util.function` package: `Consumer`, `Supplier`, `Function`, and `Predicate`. A `Function` converts a single input into a single output. A `Predicate` converts an input into a `boolean`.

The signatures for the single abstract methods in `Consumer` and `Supplier` are essentially opposites of each other:

For `Consumer<T>`:

```
void accept(T t)
```

And for `Supplier<T>`:

```
T get()
```

Since a `Consumer` takes an input and returns nothing and a `Supplier` takes nothing and returns a value, they feel like opposites. If someone was to ask me what the opposite of a `Consumer` was, my natural thought would have been `Producer`, as in Producer-Consumer problem.

So my (admittedly somewhat silly) question is, why isn't `Supplier` called `Producer`? Is there an obvious reason I'm missing?

Comment: I'm guessing, but maybe it's just because the value can be produced in one place and supplied in another one. A producer is more a constructor to me, but this is totally opinion-based...

Comment: I don't see why it matters what it's named; `Supplier<T>` and `Producer<T>` are interchangeable.  Feel free to make your own `Producer<T>` interface that extends `Supplier<T>`!

Comment: Who knows? The engineer who invented this interface decided to call it `Supplier` instead of `Producer`. You'd have to ask that person why. There is no definitive answer to this question...

Comment: My opinion would be that naming it `Producer` would look like it implies that a new value is produced for each call, whereas `Supplier` suggests that the same value could be supplied every time if desired.

Comment: Many names were considered, such as `Source`, `Supplier`, `Producer`, `Factory`, etc.  Pros and cons were raised for each, and there was extensive discussion, and the names even changed a few times before we were done.  In the end, the JSR 335 Expert Group weighed the pros and cons, and made this choice.  (It is highly likely that if we had chosen something different, some mirror-universe version of the OP would be asking "why didn't you choose Supplier...")

Comment: Thanks, Brian. I figured it was something like that.

Comment: this is a valid Q. Should not have been marked as opinion based. Why some thing is designed in such a fashion or named so are good to explore.  This Q is not calling for a debate but asking why the JDK authors decided one over the other. And any JDK user will want to know such details. Thx @BrianGoetz answered it.